# How to cache auth credentials to speed up authentication

Tags: authentication, hash, credentials, credential-reuse

I'm developing some REST API that requires a `HTTP basic auth` to access. The APIs are written in Django, and the auth is based on Django auth middleware that is: it checks against the DB, the username and password. The password is stored with the `pbkdf2`.

As you can imagine, every request takes time as it is hitting the DB (even with polls and so). Thus, I thought to `cache` (using memcache) the credentials to check them before asking the DB. The idea is to derive a key based on the BasicAuth data sent in such a way that I can query the cache and retrieve the User Info.

So far I came up with below ideas. I've the `base64` basicauth string and I can:

1. Use the value as is as key for the memcache.
2. Use a `SHA1` to hash the base64 string and use that.
3. Derive `Username:Password` and as key use the `pbkdf2(p,u,iterations)` where I encrypt the password using the username as salt. Here, I've to be careful with the iterations, otherwise it may require too much time. Empirically the iterations are < 100 to make it fast enough, which sounds a bit too low.

Even thought the cache is volatile (`120s`), the best solution (in term of trade-off between security and speed) is number 3 to me. Any inputs Or can I assume that cache is safe enough and I can use the number 1 or 2 even if they are far from being safe?

Anyone that has a better/smarter solution?

Comment: Is basic auth a hard requirement, or can you use a more standard system like user/pass, token-based, or OAuth?

Comment: well, basic auth is user/pass . I'also have Oauth for some calls. Anyway, I don't think that the auth methodo changes much in the context of the solution. no?